# React HOC not displaying wrapped component

Tags: reactjs

There aren't many useful React Higher-Order-Component (HOC) examples out there that I could find and the simple ones that exists are so simplistic they do not really even scratch the surface of what can or cannot be done using HOC's. Anyway, from what I could find, I tried the following and I am sure I am mssing something (probably obvious) because this is my first attempt to try and use HOC's:

HOC:

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export const WizardWrapper = Step => class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      page: 1
    }
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
  }

  goToPage(page) {
    this.setState({ page })
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmit, submitButtonText, step} = this.props
    let hasNext = this.props.step > this.state.page
    let hasPrev = this.state.page < this.props.step
    let nextText = hasNext ? 'Next' : submitButtonText
    return (
      <Step previousPage={hasPrev ? this.previousPage : null}
        onSubmit={hasNext ? this.nextPage : onSubmit}
        {...this.state} {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Some Component:

```
export const WizardPage = (props) => <h1>Some page</h1>
```

Attempt to display wrapped component (even if wrapping it does not actually do anything just yet):

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {WizardWrapper} from 'common/client/components/wizard/WizardWrapper'
import {WizardPage} from 'common/client/components/wizard/WizardPage'

export default class FormTest extends Component {
  render() {
    let WrapperPage = WizardWrapper(WizardPage)
    return (
      <div>
        {WrapperPage}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but nothing is displayed either. Any ideas what I am missing or doing wrong?

TIA!

Comment: I just tested this out and it works fine for me. The only thing that might be missing is `import React` in your components, unless you have some global thing going on. Literally I copied and pasted your exact code and it works.

Comment: Thanks - but now I am really baffled why it does not for me. React is pseudo-global for me because I am also using Meteor. OK I'll play some more and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this, in my case I started seeing browser console logs with:

```
maxAge 50 1 VM611:1 
maxAge 50 2 VM611:1 
maxAge 50 3 VM611:1
```

I did some digging and found out these were likely coming from NPM's LRU cache, so I ran `npm cache clean` from the console. The errors went away and my HOC's finally started displaying as expected. Apparently a corrupt NPM cache was the culprit.